# Import Jquery-moneyMask to angular2 component

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to apply a jquery-moneyMask on one of my form inputs.

```
$("#budget").maskMoney();
```

I have already imported  jquery into my component. I am missing the import for jquery-moneyMask. The error in my dev console is:

```
TypeError: $(...).maskMoney is not a function
```

The following are the versions am using:
 "jquery-maskmoney": "^3.0.2",
 "jquery": "^2.2.1"